# Why is my ubuntu ip always changing?

Tags: ip

I have my ubuntu running in a hyper-v vm instance which I access the default apache website from the windows 10 host.

everything works great but very often the ubuntu ip is changing I dont know why...

I run: `ip addr show`   to confirm it was changed...

how can I solve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ubuntu host is probably obtaining its IP address by way of DHCP. This will give you a new address more often than not.  To rectify this, get the MAC address of your VM's virtual NIC with `ip link`.  Then, take that MAC address to your router, and set ip a DHCP MAC/IP reservation (the nomenclature may vary depending on the make and model of your router) to assign it an IP that will neither change, nor conflict with any other devices or hosts on your network.